# Parsing RSS Feeds with Python

Tags: python, rss

I'm parsing the data from the Department of Labor PPI feed:
https://www.bls.gov/feed/ppi_latest.rss

Was able to get it all in to a dict of dicts, just didnt know if there was an easier way to parse this kind of data as it seems pretty common.

Goal is just to get a nice printable pandas dataframe that shows category | sub-category | data (2021, if app) | latest data.

Not so worried about the data structure, just looking for feedback on scraping RSS.

```
import feedparser
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

bls_ppi_rss = feedparser.parse("https://www.bls.gov/feed/ppi_latest.rss")
bls_ppi = bls_ppi_rss.entries[0]

soup = BeautifulSoup(bls_ppi.summary,'html.parser')

data=[i for i in soup.text.split('\n') if i][:-1]

categories = {i.text:{} for i in soup.find_all('h4')[0:]}
categories

import re

key, val, x = None, None, None

for i in data:
if i in categories.keys():
    category = i
if (i[0] == '+' or i[0] == '-'):
    val = i
    x = re.findall("[0-9]{4}", val)[0]
    data_res = re.findall("[^;(p)]*", val)[0]
elif i[-1] == ':':
    pass
else:
    key = i
if key is not None:
    if val is not None:
        for k,v in categories.items():
            if key in v.keys():
                keyWithDate = key +' ' + str(x[0])
                categories[category][keyWithDate] = [str(data_res), x]
                pass
            elif key not in v.keys():
                categories[category][key] = [str(data_res), x]
            key, val, x, data_res = None, None, None, None
            break
```

Added:

For anyone wanting to get the df code for this, it is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({f'{i} ---- {j}': categories[i][j]
                           for i in categories.keys() 
                           for j in categories[i].keys()},
                                columns=['Change', 'Data Year'],
                               orient='index')
```

Comment: What format do you want the end result in?  Can you include it as part of your question?

Comment: Now notice that I actually have None as the first key in all of my inside dicts and need to clean some unneeded lines out before i make the dict. Am also missing data where key repeats for data given for 2022 and 2021